# Login with Firebase/auth - firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3 __

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router

Auth.onAuthStateChanged is not a function

I have created a web application with React [npx create-react-app my-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app))

It is a simple application that shows a list of products from a store, from where the user can add more products.
Once finished, I have decided that registration by email is mandatory in order to see the content and be able to add products.

I need it to be mandatory to login to access the application.

Since I don't have a lot of Backend experience, I have used Firebase.

I have read information, I have seen examples and finally I have added the necessary code to my App so that when entering it, it is necessary to enter the email and password.
Once I log in, I would enter the main page `<Sidebar />`

I have repeated the steps several times and I always get the same error.

I have looked for examples elsewhere and in this same place, but I cannot solve my problem.

I show my error and some of the files that I create are the cause.

Console Errors:

```
App.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.auth.onAuthStateChanged is not a function
    at App.js:17
    at invokePassiveEffectCreate (react-dom.development.js:23487)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:23574)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:23447)
    at react-dom.development.js:23324
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:417)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:390)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js:157)
(anonymous) @ App.js:17
invokePassiveEffectCreate @ react-dom.development.js:23487
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:23574
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:23447
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:23324
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:417
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:390
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:157
index.js:1 The above error occurred in the <App> component:

    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:67:81)
    at x (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:118342:13)
    at w (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:117967:13)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:20085
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:20118
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:12318
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:12339
commitLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:20736
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:23426
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:23151
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22990
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22329
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:11327
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl @ react-dom.development.js:11322
flushSyncCallbackQueue @ react-dom.development.js:11309
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:23620
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:23447
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:23324
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:417
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:390
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:157
scheduler.development.js:171 Uncaught TypeError: firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.auth.onAuthStateChanged is not a function
    at App.js:17
    at invokePassiveEffectCreate (react-dom.development.js:23487)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:23574)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:23447)
    at react-dom.development.js:23324
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:417)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:390)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js:157)
```

**File App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router'

import firebase, { FirebaseContext } from './firebase'
import { auth } from 'firebase'

import Ordenes from './components/paginas/Ordenes'
import Menu from './components/paginas/Menu'
import NuevoPlato from './components/paginas/NuevoPlato'
import Sidebar from './components/ui/Sidebar'
import Signin from './components/Signin'

function App() {

  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(userAuth => {
      const user = {
        uid: userAuth?.uid,
        email: userAuth?.email
      }
      if (userAuth) {
        console.log(userAuth)
        setUser(user)
      } else {
        setUser(null)
      }
    })
    return unsubscribe
  }, [])

  return (
    <FirebaseContext.Provider
      value={{
        firebase
      }}
    >
      <div className="md:flex min-h-screen" >
      <Sidebar />
        <div className="md:w-2/5 xl:w-4/5 p-6">
          {user ? <Sidebar /> : <Signin />}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="md:w-2/5 xl:w-4/5 p-6">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Ordenes />} />
          <Route path="/menu" element={<Menu />} />
          <Route path="/nuevo-plato" element={<NuevoPlato />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </FirebaseContext.Provider>


  )
}

export default App
```

**File Signin.js**

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
//import { auth } from '../firebase'
import { auth } from 'firebase';
const Signin = () => {
    const emailRef = useRef(null);
    const passwordRef = useRef(null);
    const signUp = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            emailRef.current.value,
            passwordRef.current.value
        ).then(user => {
            console.log(user)
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
    const signIn = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            emailRef.current.value,
            passwordRef.current.value
        ).then(user => {
            console.log(user)
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
    return (
        <div className="mb-4">
            <form action="">
                <h1>Sign in</h1>
                <input
                className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                ref={emailRef} type="email" placeholder="email"/>
                <input 
                className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                ref={passwordRef} type="password" />
                <button onClick={signIn}>Sign in </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Signin




**File firebase.js**

import app from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/storage'
import 'firebase/auth'

import firebaseConfig from './config'

class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    if (!app.apps.length) {
      app.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
    }
    this.db = app.firestore()
    this.storage = app.storage()
    this.auth = app.auth()
  }
}

const firebase = new Firebase()
export default firebase
```

**File package.json**

```
{
  "name": "mYStore",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "firebase": "^7.19.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-firebase-file-uploader": "^2.4.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run watch:css && react-scripts start",
    "build": "npm run build:css && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build:css": "postcss src/css/tailwind.css -o src/css/main.css",
    "watch:css": "postcss src/css/tailwind.css -o src/css/main.css"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.3.1",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "postcss-cli": "^8.3.1",
    "react-router": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.7"
  }
}
```

**This is the structure of the application**

[image]

Comment: Can you share your package.json?

Comment: Add package.json @Dharmaraj

Comment: Did you try changing the import to `import { auth } from './firebase'` ?

Comment: I get the following error: `./src/App.js
Attempted import error: 'auth' is not exported from './firebase'.`

Comment: That path should be to the file from where your are exporting firebase. Can you try writing correct relative path?

Comment: it's a folder called firebase outside of the components folder.
firebase / firebase.js
when I write: `"import {auth} ...."` this path is automatically written:
`import {auth} from 'firebase'`

Comment: Try my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try importing `auth` from `firebase.js` and not Firebase module:

```js
import fireObj from './firebase'
// valid path here    ^^
```

The path should be relative to the file where you are importing it. For example, to import it in `signin.js`, the path should be:

```
import fireObj from '../firebase/firebase.js'

const auth = fireObj.auth

auth.onAuthStateChanged(...)
```

Also you are exporting a single object of Firebase class so try changing your import as shown above.

Comment: Thank @Dharmaraj .The correct option is the one above, since this way, `'../firebase/firebase.js'`, does not access.
I already got it to work.
But the application keeps opening in the main menu, it shows the registration form, but it also shows the main menu of my application, and I need to access the menu, it is necessary to register. Should I ask another question for this?

Comment: @MiguelEspeso the new issues seems to be related with react components so it may be better to ask  another one to get more visibility.

Comment: I have added a question to try to solve the Login problem, I cannot enter the application. I leave you a link maybe you have a free moment and review [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69026790/how-to-make-registration-mandatory-with-firebase-auth-in-my-react-app). I would appreciate. Thanks @Dhamaraj