# How to make registration mandatory with Firebase auth in my React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router

**EDIT TO ADD DETAILS**

The application must be started with a page with a form, enter email and password and when Login takes us to the menu screen, which I show in the screenshot.
However, when I enter the email and password, the application does not move.
The log works, because a `consolelog()` shows it to me

It's the second screenshot

I do not understand what I have wrong.
Now I show the modified App.js file to show the form, but when I register, the application does not reach the Menu, page `<Sidebar />`

**archivo App.js modificado**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router'

import firebase, { FirebaseContext } from './firebase'
//import { auth } from 'firebase' 
import firebaseObj from './firebase'
import Ordenes from './components/paginas/Ordenes'
import Menu from './components/paginas/Menu'
import NuevoPlato from './components/paginas/NuevoPlato'
import Sidebar from './components/ui/Sidebar'
import Signin from './components/Signin'

const auth = firebaseObj.auth

function App() {

  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(userAuth => {
      const user = {
        uid: userAuth?.uid,
        email: userAuth?.email
      }
      if (userAuth) {
        console.log(userAuth)
        setUser(user)
      } else {
        setUser(null)
      }
    })
    return unsubscribe
  }, [])

  return (
    <FirebaseContext.Provider
      value={{
        firebase
      }}
    >
      <div className="md:flex min-h-screen" >
        <div className="md:w-2/5 xl:w-4/5 p-6">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Signin />} />
            <Route path="/sidebar" element={<Sidebar />} />
            <Route path="/ordenes" element={<Ordenes />} />
            <Route path="/menu" element={<Menu />} />
            <Route path="/nuevo-plato" element={<NuevoPlato />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>

    </FirebaseContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default App
```

[image]

[image]

I have created a web application with React (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app. --- npx create-react-app my-app)

It is a simple application with three screens: Main, Menu, New Products
The App that shows a list of products from a store, from where the user can add more products.
Once finished, I have decided that registration by email is mandatory in order to see the content and be able to add products.
I have added the appropriate configuration to get the login through Firebase, the application always starts directly, although it shows the registration form.

The configuration of App.js is correct, but I don't know how to make my application start from Signin, and once the email and user name were entered, I was sent to the application

I have tried several ways, and in all of them it starts the application directly.
I have added Signin to App.js, but I need to see what App.js shows, it is necessary to enter the email and password.
Now, there is the application menu

**File App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router'

import firebase, { FirebaseContext } from './firebase'
//import { auth } from 'firebase' 
import firebaseObj from './firebase'
import Ordenes from './components/paginas/Ordenes'
import Menu from './components/paginas/Menu'
import NuevoPlato from './components/paginas/NuevoPlato'
import Sidebar from './components/ui/Sidebar'
import Signin from './components/Signin'

const auth = firebaseObj.auth

function App() {

  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(userAuth => {
      const user = {
        uid: userAuth?.uid,
        email: userAuth?.email
      }
      if (userAuth) {
        console.log(userAuth)
        setUser(user)
      } else {
        setUser(null)
      }
    })
    return unsubscribe
  }, [])

  return (
    <FirebaseContext.Provider
      value={{
        firebase
      }}
    >
      <div className="md:flex min-h-screen" >
        <Sidebar />

        <div className="md:w-2/5 xl:w-4/5 p-6">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Ordenes />} />
            <Route path="/menu" element={<Menu />} />
            <Route path="/nuevo-producto" element={<NuevoProducto />} />
          </Routes>

        </div>

      </div>

    </FirebaseContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default App
```

**File Signin.js**

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
//import { auth } from '../firebase'
import firebaseObj from '../firebase/firebase'

const auth = firebaseObj.auth

const Signin = () => {
    const emailRef = useRef(null);
    const passwordRef = useRef(null);
    const signUp = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            emailRef.current.value,
            passwordRef.current.value
        ).then(user => {
            console.log(user)
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
    const signIn = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            emailRef.current.value,
            passwordRef.current.value
        ).then(user => {
            console.log(user)
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
    return (
        <div className="mb-4">
            <form action="">
                <h1>Sign in</h1>
                <input
                className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                ref={emailRef} type="email" placeholder="email"/>
                <input 
                className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                ref={passwordRef} type="password" />
                <button onClick={signIn}>Sign in </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Signin
```

Comment: What do you mean with "The application starts directly altought it shows the registration form"? Do you have any screenshots and a little bit more explanation how it should behave and how it behaves now?

Comment: Thank you @TarikHuber and sorry for the delay. The application must start on a page of a form to enter the email and password, and once done, it must lead me to the menu screen. But I created the application and then added the Signin method, and I can't implement it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you don't get to the `SignIn` page after you register is that there is no logic for it. If you make just a simple if statament like here it should work:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router";

import firebase, { FirebaseContext } from "./firebase";
//import { auth } from 'firebase'
import firebaseObj from "./firebase";
import Ordenes from "./components/paginas/Ordenes";
import Menu from "./components/paginas/Menu";
import NuevoPlato from "./components/paginas/NuevoPlato";
import Sidebar from "./components/ui/Sidebar";
import Signin from "./components/Signin";

const auth = firebaseObj.auth;

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((userAuth) => {
      const user = {
        uid: userAuth?.uid,
        email: userAuth?.email,
      };
      if (userAuth) {
        console.log(userAuth);
        setUser(user);
      } else {
        setUser(null);
      }
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  if (!user) {
    return (
      <div className="md:flex min-h-screen">
        <div className="md:w-2/5 xl:w-4/5 p-6">
          <Signin />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <FirebaseContext.Provider
        value={{
          firebase,
        }}
      >
        <div className="md:flex min-h-screen">
          <div className="md:w-2/5 xl:w-4/5 p-6">
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Sidebar />} />
              <Route path="/sidebar" element={<Sidebar />} />
              <Route path="/ordenes" element={<Ordenes />} />
              <Route path="/menu" element={<Menu />} />
              <Route path="/nuevo-plato" element={<NuevoPlato />} />
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </div>
      </FirebaseContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

That is just for example purpose. I would recommend to put the auth state listener into a Provider and create custom routes that automaticaly reroute to the `SignIn` page if no user is logged in.

[Here](https://github.com/TarikHuber/react-most-wanted/tree/master/packages/base-shell/src/providers/Auth) you have an example of such an Provider that I use in every of my projects.

An [here](https://github.com/TarikHuber/react-most-wanted/tree/master/packages/base-shell/src/components) is an example of those custom routes that are listening to that provier.

Comment: Thanks @TariKHuber . I have tested your code but the application starts with a blank page. It is working because the console.log (userAuth) of line 24 shows the user that is registered in firebase, but the screen is blank. The intention is that when the app starts, it shows the form, and when I enter the correct email and password, it goes to </ Sidebar>.
Your examples are very interesting, but it is still somewhat complicated to my knowledge. I try to learn each a little more. I've seen your work and it's amazing

Comment: Thx. I have updated the code. Can you pls try it with that one to.

Comment: Do you have a problem that the auth state stays persisted after you revisit the page?

Comment: There is no problem, everything works perfectly. I only needed a button to close the session when the user finished working in the App. In this way, the administrator panel is not open, I have added a button on the `</ Sidebar>` screen to disconnect whenever I want. Is there a method for the App to return to the `Signin` page after a certain time?

Comment: Thx. Happy to hear that I could help :)

Comment: Do you have any ideas on this? Could you create a function so that the application closes automatically after a period of inactivity in the App and it is necessary to enter the email and password again? Do you know a site where I can read something about automatically logging out? Thanks

Comment: The auth state is saved on the webside by Firebase so you would need to logout your user each time the app closes or the tab gets closed. You could just logout the user and clear the whole app storage when that happens.